# React Navigation:How to disable tab navigator swipe when in a stack navigator

Tags: reactjs, navigation, swipe, react-navigation

React Navigation on Android:
When in a stack navigator, how to disable swipe of tab navigator. 
thx

Answer (score 1):

```
ABCNav.navigationOptions = ({ navigation, screenProps }) => {
    if (navigation.state.index != 0) {
        return {
            tabBarVisible: false,
            swipeEnabled: false, //disable swipe inside StackNavigator
        };
    }
    return {
        tabBarVisible: true, 
//enable swipe function for first screen
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to each screen in the StackNavigator:

```
static navigationOptions = {
  swipeEnabled: false,
}
```